# Using mapply to individual elements of list

Tags: r, list, function, switch-statement, mapply

I have a list:

```
ls <- list(c(a,b),c(i,j))
```

```
a<-"char1"
b<-"char2"
i<-"char4"
j<-"char5"
```

I need to apply the following functions to individual elements of a list

```
f1<- function(x) {
  switch(x,
         "char1"=1,
         "char2"=2,
         "char3"=3
  )
}
```

```
f2 <- function(x){
  switch(x,
         "char4"=1,
         "char5"=2,
         "char6"=3
  )
}
```

This is what I tried, but I get an error

```
mapply(function(dat, fun) fun(dat), ls, list(f1,f2))
```

> Error in switch(x, `char1` = 1, `char2` = 2, `char3` = 3) : 
>       EXPR must be a length 1 vector

I see that `x` in `switch` should be of length 1. Right now, I think it is taking `x` as `c(a, b)`.

Basically I would like to apply `f1` to `a` with `x=a`, apply `f1` to `b` with `x=b`, apply `f2` to `i` with `x=i`, apply `f2` to `j` with `x=j`

When I try the mapply for 1 function over 1 list, it works the right way

mapply(function(dat, fun) fun(dat), c(a,b), list(f1))

Comment: Note that `ls` is a function name, 2) list elements needs to be quoted or is it a object identifier.  Also, what is `dat`

Comment: I edited my question. I changed ls to a different variable, it still doesn't work. I mapplied  f1 to c(a,b) alone  and it works the way I want . f1 gets applied to a, with x=a, f1 gets applied to b with x=b in switch. dat can anything . I can also define : mapply(function(x,y)y(x) ls,list(f1,f2))

Comment: Can you just copy/paste `ls <- list(c(a,b),c(i,j))` in console and see if it works?

Comment: Yes, Don't see a problem with that. Have included values of a,b,c and d in the original question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions take only a vector of length 1.  So, we can `Vectorize` it

```
Map(function(dat, fun) fun(dat), ls, list(Vectorize(f1), Vectorize(f2)))
#[[1]]
#char1 char2 
#    1     2 

#[[2]]
#char4 char5 
#    1     2
```